# Why applying Stokes' theorem, and then, Divergence Theorem, gives always zero.

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

The other day, I was at my exam, and I had the following exercise:

Given a vector field, $\mathbf F(x, y, z)$, calculate the following integral over a surface $S$:
$$
\iint_{S} (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S
$$
My first intuition, was to use Stoke's Theorem and solve it using a line integral. The result turns out to be $0$. So then I thought: if you apply Divergences theorem you'd get the same result, because:
$$
\int_{C} \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \iint_{S} (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S = \iiint_W \nabla \cdot \mathbf (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \; dV
$$
But $\nabla \cdot \mathbf (\nabla \times \mathbf F) = 0$, then:
$$
\int_{C} \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \iint_{S} (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S = \iiint_W 0 \;dV = 0
$$
But, it is well-known that not all line integrals are zero. So, this is a mere coincidence or has a more deep meaning. I understand this might be because the region in which this integrals are defined. But can someone explain me this in depth, why:
$$
\int_{\partial^2 W} \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \iint_{\partial W} (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S = \iiint_W \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf F) \;dV = 0
$$
not always works?

Comment: So you are assuming that $S$ is always the boundary of a volume $W$, right? That's not true.

Comment: For Gauss (divergence) you need $\partial W=S\,.$ For Stokes you need $C=\partial S\,.$  If $S$ is the boundary of $W$ this implies that $C=0\,.$ Or in other words: Stokes integrates over a *non closed* surface, while Gauss integrates over a closed surface.